# List out text files from given directory in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ubuntu

Writing shell script to sort text file data from given directory with for loop in ubuntu as:

```
   echo "Enter directory Name"
   read dr
   path= ` find /home/user -name $dr `
   for x in ` ls *.txt $path ` 
     do
       sort $x
     done
   echo "------Script finished-------"
```

But this script is giving me error or message like(even tho' i have text files):

```
   ls: cannot access *.txt: No Such File or Directoy
```

I think there is problem with ls command,Is it syntactically wrong or what ? How to list out text files from given directory path ?

Comment: Don't you just mean `for x in \` ls $path/*.txt \` ` instead?

Comment: That was error in script, I solved it. @JeffY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modified example.  I do not know why backticks did not work so I used ():

```
echo "Enter directory Name"
   read dr
   path=( $(find /home/user -type d -name $dr))
   for x in `ls $path/*.txt`
     do
       sort $x
     done
   echo "------Script finished-------"
```

Comment: Three things: 1) I want user to enter just directory name,not directory path. Example: it could be "dir3" where "/home/dir1/dir2/dir3". thats why i have used find.
2) Want to perform task with for loop only.
3) Want to perform sort content not file names.

Comment: I solved it as jeff mention in comment, and i think your script is correct too.